# Mocking Multiple Implementations of the interface used as IEnumerable in DI

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, moq

Using ASP.NET core Dependency injection to inject multiple implementations of an Interface.
This is how my code looks:

`public factory(IEnumerable<ISomeInterface> interfaceImplList){}`

`public class Impl1:ISomeInterface(){}`

`public class Impl2:ISomeInterface(){}`

`public class Impl3:ISomeInterface(){}`

`public class Impl4:ISomeInterface(){}`

All the above implementations are injected into the factory and factory will return some implementation based on some configs (Not related to the question)

Now I want to mock this factory using moq. Is there a way to do that, or should I create all the mocked implementations of above classes and them put them in a IEnumerable and pass?

Also another question, is it even a good unit testing practice to create a factory to return mocked instance or should I directly unit test the individual implementations?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Krj3-h198KQ

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then edit the question to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.